# update to update npde_modules folder using npm install -

Tags: vue.js

while do migration my project from vue 2 to vue 3, I upgrade my node version to LTS (v18.X).
after upgrade node I delete node_modules folder and regenerate using npm install, i getting below error

```
npm WARN deprecated stable@0.1.8: Modern JS already guarantees Array#sort() is a stable sort, so this library is deprecated. See the compatibility table on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#browser_compatibility
npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated request-promise-native@1.0.9: request-promise-native has been deprecated because it extends the now deprecated request package, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated request-promise@4.2.6: request-promise has been deprecated because it extends the now deprecated request package, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated mkdirp@0.5.4: Legacy versions of mkdirp are no longer supported. Please update to mkdirp 1.x. (Note that the API surface has changed to use Promises in 1.x.)
npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 does not receive security updates since 2019. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x fewer dependencies
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 does not receive security updates since 2019. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x fewer dependencies
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated browserslist@2.11.3: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools.
npm WARN deprecated left-pad@1.3.0: use String.prototype.padStart()
npm WARN deprecated w3c-hr-time@1.0.2: Use your platform's native performance.now() and performance.timeOrigin.
npm WARN deprecated debug@3.2.6: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1. (https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/797)
npm WARN deprecated html-webpack-plugin@3.2.0: 3.x is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated sane@4.1.0: some dependency vulnerabilities fixed, support for node < 10 dropped, and newer ECMAScript syntax/features added
npm WARN deprecated vue-test-utils@1.0.0-beta.11: VUE-TEST-UILS WARN: vue-test-utils has moved to a scoped package. The new repository is available @vue/test-utils. To install the new package, run npm install --save-dev @vue/test-utils
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated vm2@3.9.19: The library contains critical security issues and should not be used for production! The maintenance of the project has been discontinued. Consider migrating your code to isolated-vm.
npm WARN deprecated uglify-es@3.3.9: support for ECMAScript is superseded by `uglify-js` as of v3.13.0
npm WARN deprecated axios@0.18.1: Critical security vulnerability fixed in v0.21.1. For more information, see https://github.com/axios/axios/pull/3410
npm WARN deprecated svgo@1.3.2: This SVGO version is no longer supported. Upgrade to v2.x.x.
npm WARN deprecated tar@2.2.2: This version of tar is no longer supported, and will not receive security updates. Please upgrade asap.
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3.23.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Some versions have web compatibility issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Source\prdfolder\prdfolder.ui_original\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Source\prdfolder\prdfolder.ui_original\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\Source\\prdfolder\\prdfolder.ui_original\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@18.17.1 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Source\prdfolder\prdfolder.ui_original\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Source\prdfolder\prdfolder.ui_original\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Source\prdfolder\prdfolder.ui_original\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Source\prdfolder\prdfolder.ui_original\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Source\prdfolder\prdfolder.ui_original\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Source\prdfolder\prdfolder.ui_original\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:210:21)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed  python2 Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Source\prdfolder\prdfolder.ui_original\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Source\prdfolder\prdfolder.ui_original\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Source\prdfolder\prdfolder.ui_original\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Source\prdfolder\prdfolder.ui_original\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Source\prdfolder\prdfolder.ui_original\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Source\prdfolder\prdfolder.ui_original\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:210:21) {
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed }
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Source\prdfolder\prdfolder.ui_original\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Source\prdfolder\prdfolder.ui_original\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Source\prdfolder\prdfolder.ui_original\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Source\prdfolder\prdfolder.ui_original\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Source\prdfolder\prdfolder.ui_original\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Source\prdfolder\prdfolder.ui_original\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:210:21)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed  python Error: not found: python
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Source\prdfolder\prdfolder.ui_original\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Source\prdfolder\prdfolder.ui_original\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Source\prdfolder\prdfolder.ui_original\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Source\prdfolder\prdfolder.ui_original\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Source\prdfolder\prdfolder.ui_original\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Source\prdfolder\prdfolder.ui_original\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:210:21) {
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed }
npm ERR! gyp verb could not find "python". checking python launcher
npm ERR! gyp verb could not find "python". guessing location
npm ERR! gyp verb ensuring that file exists: C:\Python27\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
```

But, if I use older version node, no issue to generate node_modules. can anyone advise how to resolve this.

Comment: Read the actual error. It says there `ensuring that file exists: C:\Python27\python.exe ... Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.`  It would be prudent for you to check that the python exe exists there and/or python env variable is set correctly.

Comment: I don't use any phython in my app, actually same code woks fine in vue 2 without phyton, i just wondered why need phython

Comment: This error was fixed, after installed python. also few other config needed to do. python is needed for node-gyp, refer below links for steps https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-gyp/v/9.4.0

Answer (score 0):

Install python resolved this issue.
also refer below link for further configuration.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-gyp/v/9.4.0